# Error CS0234 - Namespace 'Xna' does not exist in namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, xna

After encountering a few problems regarding the **CS0234** error stated in the title, I looked up a solution, found [here](http://flatredball.com/visual-studio-2017-xna-setup/), and followed all of the steps to install the *XNA Game Studio*.

I got confirmation from the *Developer command prompt* that the requested files and libraries were added to the global cache, but I still got the following errors after compiling my program again:

> GraphicsHandler.cs(11,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Xna' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Camera.cs(6,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Xna' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Application.cs(9,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Xna' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> GraphicsHandler.cs(14,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DrawableGameContent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I fix these **CS0234** errors?

Comment: Have you added a reference to the appropriate assembly(ies)?  It looks like you added everything to the GAC, so the should be on the main tab in the Add Reference dialog. You get that by right-clicking the project and choosing "Add Reference".

Comment: @Flydog57 no luck.  I cannot seem to find the option to add a reference.  It's not under the "Project" tab, and right-clicking on anything hasn't produced any results yet.  I'm using Visual Studio 2017 if that helps.

Comment: I did a bit of research and, apparently, i'm missing a DLL needed to add references.  Strange.  I'll download it and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: Turns out, I had not created a project for my... project.  I did so and the option appeared.  Thank you nonetheless.